# Python tkinter start and stop loop?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

Ive been trying to make a program with 2 buttons, pressing one of them will start an infinite loop and pressing the other one will stop it.

All the methods ive tried will just pause the loop.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
s = 0

def stopit():
    s = 1
    print "stoped"
#
def callback():

    if s == 0:
        while True:
            print "called the callback!"
            time.sleep(3)
            if s == 1:
                break
            #
        #
    #
#

root = Tk()

def main():


    # create a menu
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)

    b = Button(root, command=stopit)
    b.pack()


    filemenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=callback)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=callback)
    filemenu.add_separator()
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=callback)

    helpmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=callback)

    mainloop()
    time.sleep(3)
#

main()
```

Comment: What is the question? Also, please post the relevant code.

Comment: Im trying to make it so if you press one button it will run a loop and if you press another button it will stop it.

Comment: @tobias_k. What do you mean? I want it so it breaks out of the loop instead of just pausing.

Comment: When I run the program, the GUI just freezes, because the `callback` method never finishes, so I can not press the "stop" button at all. You should try to use `Tkinter.after` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- Your `callback` method never finishes (due to the infinite loop), causing the GUI to freeze. Instead, use the `after` method to schedule another execution of `callback` after the method finishes.
- Your `stopit` method creates a local variable `s` instead of changing the global one. Use the `global` keyword to fix this.

Change the two methods to something like this, and it should work:

```
def stopit():
    global s
    s = 1
    print "stopped"

def callback():
    if s == 0:
        print "called the callback!"
        root.after(3000, callback)
```

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/gmwc9nTx but i got this error Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1473, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "gui.py", line 12, in callback
    if s == 0:
NameError: global name 's' is not defined

Comment: I fixed the error by doing this http://pastebin.com/SwknxkCs but now when i click stop it just says stoped but keeps going on