# Acquire data and plot them with a "start" and "stop" button using tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I want my program to acquire and plot datas from a force sensor as soon as i press a "start" button and that when i press a "pause" button, i stop my program. The problem here is that when i press "start", it works (I can see my graph) but i cannot press the "pause" button (it refreshes all the time). See below my code.

Thank you for your help !

````
"""
Created on Tue Nov 16 17:38:33 2021

@author: admin
"""


import serial
import struct
import platform
import multiprocessing

import time
import numpy as np
import csv
# from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter


class MeasurementConverter:
    def convertValue(self, bytes):
        pass


class ForceMeasurementConverterKG(MeasurementConverter):
    def __init__(self, F_n, S_n, u_e):
        self.F_n = F_n
        self.S_n = S_n
        self.u_e = u_e

    def convertValue(self, value):
        A = struct.unpack('>H', value)[0]
        # return (A - 0x8000) * (self.F_n / self.S_n) * (self.u_e / 0x8000)
        return self.F_n / self.S_n * ((A - 0x8000) / 0x8000) * self.u_e * 2


class GSV3USB:
    def __init__(self, com_port, baudrate=38400):
        com_path = f'/dev/ttyUSB{com_port}' if platform.system(
        ) == 'Linux' else f'COM{com_port}'
        # print(f'Using COM: {com_path}')
        self.sensor = serial.Serial(com_path, baudrate)
        self.converter = ForceMeasurementConverterKG(10, 0.499552, 2)



    def read_value(self):
        self.sensor.read_until(b'\xA5')
        read_val = self.sensor.read(2)
        return self.converter.convertValue(read_val)


# GSV3USB(6).sensor.close()

   
            
# initialization of datas
gsv_data=[]
temps=[]
t_0=time.time()

def stop():

    window.poll = False


def data_gsv():
    dev = GSV3USB(6)
    # fig=plt.figure()
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    i=0
    # line1, = ax.plot(temps, gsv_data)

    
    while window.poll:
        

        gsv_data.append(dev.read_value())
        t1=time.time()-t_0
        temps.append(t1)
        
        
        # I can print the datas without noticing any lags
        # print(dev.read_value())   
        # I cannot plot the datas without noticing any lags
        plt.plot(temps,gsv_data)
        plt.draw ()
        plt.axis([temps[i]-6,temps[i]+6,-2,10])
        plt.pause(0.00000001)
        plt.clf()
        # plt.close()
        i=i+1
        # I cannot pause without noticing any lags
        # time.sleep(0.0001)
        # print(dev.read_value())   
        
        # # I cannot save datas without noticing any lags
        # with open('student_gsv.csv', 'w') as f: 
        #     write = csv.writer(f) 
        #     write.writerow(gsv_data)                 
        
    else:
        
        print("Stopped long running process.")
        return
 

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.poll = True
window.title("Loop")
startButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Start", command = data_gsv)
stopButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Pause", command = stop)
startButton.pack()
stopButton.pack()
window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: don't use a `while` loop, it blocks `mainloop` from updating

Answer (score 0):

The Tkinter mainloop is blocked by the while loop and stop button action is never called upon here. Repeated clicking of the stop button can lead to the whole GUI freezing. One option to avoid this will be using the `threading` module. The data reading loop can be executed in a different thread and can be started or stopped from GUI without many issues.

```py
import threading

t1 = threading.Thread(target=data_gsv, args=())
.
.
.

def start():
    t1.start()
.
.
.

startButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Start", command = start)  # data_gsv -> start
```

Now, the stop button is not frozen and stops the loop. This is a basic solution, please feel free to modify as required. Read more about threading here:

[Real Python.com](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)
[Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Hi Jarvis, Thanks for the answer

Comment: Similar question with different approach can be found here : [Python tkinter start and stop loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457148/python-tkinter-start-and-stop-loop?rq=1)